# Enforce browser to treat element as a link in JS

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I have a table with rows that handle `onClick` events which redirect users to another route based on `keyRow`. Therefore, I'd like to have a context menu typical for links (as follows):

[image]

However, I see a common context menu:

[image]

What could I do to have the context menu typical for links?

Comment: make those elements `<a>` tags

Comment: You're not going to be able to have the context menu you are looking for if you don't use an a tag.

Comment: You can write a custom `oncontextmenu` handler.

Comment: Thank you guys for your tips. ASAIK, I shouldn't wrap divs in `<a>` tags, should I? I'm using Table from Ant Design (components library) so I decided to use `onRow.onClick` to redirect user to another page and I'm going to create custom simple context menu with `<a target-"_blank" />`

Ref: https://ant.design/components/table/